# Could not get result in already running form.why? It opens up another form with result.

Tags: c#, winforms

I have A and B forms.

when i run A form will display all the values in datagridview by clicking start button.In this same form one labellink is there.Once i click the labelink B form will display with combobox and one button.

now i choose one option and click the button which i want to see the values in datagridview of A Form.

My issue is when i selected choice in B form, the results should come in already opened A form but where as in my case it will open up another new A form and shows the result.I dont want to open again A Form and process the result.

How can i do this? simple solution to acheive it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass instance of FormA to FormB

```
public class FormB{

   public FormB(FormA formA){
    this.FormA=formA;
  }

  private void UpdateFormA(){
    formA.SetResult(...);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an MVC architecture, where the controller 'knows' which forms are open. That way form B tells the controller to display form A, the controller decides one form A is already open, and advises form A to update itself.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by AISki use MVC else use events and delegates. Fire event from FORM B and subscribe it in FORM A.